# Beautiful Soup changes html code in a wrong way

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse html code using Beautiful Soup. I make get-requests via requests module in Python and then convert html code to bs object. But I was faced with a problem. When I make BeautifulSoup object it changes the source code in a wrong way. I can make sure that it's exactly fault of Beautiful Soup through comparing Soup object and response.text. For example, it changes the place of table tag.

Here the code:

```
page = requests.get(address)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')


print(page.text)
print(soup)
```

The output is:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      some tags
    </td>
  <tr>
    <td>some tags
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          some tags
        </td>
</table>
      <tr>
        <td>some tags
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Because of this changes I can't parse the table correctly because table tag in bs object closes before the all tr tags close. What I should to do to resolve my problem?

Here is the full code of the page I'm trying to parse:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable=0;">
    <title>
        три версии нас</title>
    <meta name="Description" content="Онлайн библиотека Траума ePub + FB2 + Mobi. Скачать книги для электронных читалок, iOS и Android устройств и Amazon Kindle">
    <meta name="Keywords" content="Traum Library, traumlib, traum, Библиотека, Библиотека Траума, онлайн, Траум, Траума, скачать, бесплатно, электронные, книги, epub, FB2, Mobi, iBooks, Kindle, online, library, Traum, books, ebooks">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <script src="/likely.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/likely.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html {
            height: 100%;
            font-size: 100%;
        }

        body {
            font-size: 0.625em;
            position: relative;
            min-height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            background-image: url(/back.png);
        }

        #book_header {
            padding-top: 5px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-bottom: -5px;
            color: #394263;
        }

        header {
            border-bottom-style: solid;
            border-bottom-width: 1px;
            border-bottom-color: grey;
        }

        header {
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 68px;
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
        }

        #content {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding-top: 70px;
            padding-bottom: 70px;
        }

        footer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .books p {
            margin-top: 15px;
        }

        .books a {
            position: absolute;
            left: 70px;
        }

        p,
        table,
        td {
            font: normal 1.2em sans-serif;
            margin: 10px;
            max-width: 768px;
        }

        h2 {
            font: normal 1.4em sans-serif;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        td,
        tr {
            padding: 4px;
        }

        a:link,
        a:visited,
        tr {
            color: #394263;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
            border-color: #b2ccf0;
        }

        a:hover,
        tr:hover {
            color: #CC0000;
            border-color: #f0b2b2
        }

        .pluso a {
            border-bottom: none
        }

        ;
        tbody tr:hover {
            background: RGB(235, 235, 235);
        }

        form {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        td:first-child + td {
            color: gray;
        }

        .speech {
            border: 1px solid #DDD;
            width: 300px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0
        }

        .speech input {
            border: 0;
            width: 240px;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 30px;
        }

        .speech img {
            float: right;
            width: 40px
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        if (document.cookie == '') {
            var date = new Date(2030, 1, 1);
            document.cookie = "book-format=mobi; path=/; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body OnLoad="document.search.find.focus();">
    <header>
        <h2><a href=/>Библиотека</a> Траума 2.33 &nbsp;Формат:&nbsp;
<select id='format-select' name='format-select'> 
<option value='epub'>ePub</option><option value='fb2'>FB2</option><option selected value='mobi'>Mobi</option></select><br>
<form name=search action="/">
<input placeholder="&nbsp;поиск книги / автора" type="search" results="10" name="find" name="q" id="transcript" style="width:223px;height:23px;" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="on" spellcheck="true" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Найти!" style="width:65px;height:23px">
</form></header><div id=content>
<section><p>Найдено в русской библиотеке Траума: 0</p>
<table></table></section><p>Найдено в английской библиотеке Траума: 0</p>
<table></table><p>Найдено в библиотеке lib.rus.ec (<b>только FB2</b>): 1<br><font size=1>Поиск идет только при отсутствии результатов в TraumLib.</font></p>
<div id='librusec' style='display:block;'><table><tr><td><div id=book_header><a href="/?find=Барнетт Лора">Барнетт Лора</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></div><tr><td><a href="/d.php?file=653860&name=Барнетт - Три версии нас.fb2"">Барнетт - Три версии нас<td>1.47MB</td></tr>
</div></table></div><footer><font size=2>
<div class="likely" data-url="http://lib.it.cx" data-title="Библиотека Траума 2.33 ePub/FB2/Mobi" style="margin:10px;">
  <div class="twitter"></div>
  <div class="facebook"></div>
  <div class="gplus"></div>
  <div class="vkontakte"></div>
  <div class="telegram"></div>
  <div class="odnoklassniki"></div>
  <div class="linkedin"></div>
  <div class="whatsapp"></div>
  <div class="pinterest" data-media="i/pinnable.jpg"></div>
</div>
<pre style=\"margin:10px;\">

Найдено в БД за 0.0159 с</div>
</footer>
</body>
<script>
var sel = document.getElementById("format-select");
sel.onchange = function() {
    var date = new Date( 2030,1,1 );
    var format = sel.value;
    document.cookie="book-format=" + format + "; path=/; expires="+date.toUTCString();
    location.reload();
};
</script>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-49300233-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the page you are parsing so that the problem can be replicated? Thanks.

Comment: @cooleck share your website url.

Comment: I added source code of the page in my question. This is website url http://lib.it.cx/?find=%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81

Answer (score 0):

Resolve problem with switching from 'html.parser' to 'lxml'. But if somebody know why html.parser didn't work correctly I would appreciate if you share.

Comment: html.parser doesn't try to fix broken HTML, but lxml and even html5lib will try and do some correction. It cannot be expected that parsers will properly parse malformed HTML, but some can handle some malformed HTML, some more so than others.

Answer (score 0):

`page.text` is not properly formatted: the first tr element is never closed

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      some tags
    </td>
  <tr>             <------------ first <tr> is not closed with </tr>
    <td>some tags
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yep, but I mustn't influence on place of table tag after converting in bs4